# Definition of continuity on an open interval (a, b)

Tags: functions, continuity, definition

I'm working on some questions on continuity, and one question was to define what it meant for a function $\ f:[a, b]→ℝ$ to be continuous on $\ [a,b]$.

The definition given is :
$\ f:[a, b]→ℝ$ is continuous on $\ [a, b]$ if, $\ \forall\ c\ \epsilon\ [a,b]$ and $\ \forall\ (x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset [a,b]$ such that $\ \lim_{n→\infty} (x_{n}) = c $, it follows that $\ \lim_{n→\infty}f(x_n) = f(c)$.

This makes sense to me, and I'm more than happy with the definition. However, when I answered this question I wrote :

$\ f$ is continuous on$\ [a,b]$ if $\ \forall\ c\ \epsilon\ [a,b]$, given $\ ε > 0, \exists\ \delta > 0$ such that : $\ |x-c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(c)| < ε$.

Are these definitions equivalent? Is there a problem with my definition? I see that the difference arises from me using the epsilon-delta definition of coninuity, but does this break anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes these are equivalent definitions, which you can try to prove by $\epsilon-\delta$ definitions.

Comment: The two conditions are equivalent. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643588/heine-definition-of-limit-of-a-function-at-infinity-using-sequences

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason the former definition is used rather than the latter? I notice that the definition I gave is slightly more compact.

Comment: @JimmyDiddler Both definitions has advantages and disadvantages. As long as I'm aware the second definition is the classical one (the one given by Cauchy or so you can check the Wikipedia page about this) this definition is also a little more "natural" (in my opinion) but I agree that in some occasions the first definition is much more convenient.