# Approaching a point for evaluating the limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

According to the Stewart's book :

> If $f(x,y) \to L_1$ as $x \to (a, b)$ along a path $C_1$ and $f(x,y) \to L_2$ as $x \to (a, b)$ along a path $C_2$, where $L_1 \not= L_2$, then $\lim_{x \to (a,b)}{f(x,y)}$  does  not exist.

The ambiguous part of the statement is **"path"** . What is the path ? It has to be a function ? Is it continuous at $(a , b)$ ? In general , what are the conditions for being path ?

Comment: Formal definition is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)

Comment: @FormerMath I think in this context , the definition of path is different .

Comment: no, it is the same. As a personal side-note, I think that in a course of multivariable calculus the concept is not treated formally because it is not that important at this stage. With "a continuous line approaching to the point" is more than enough. The main goal of a multivariable calculus course are Green and Stokes Theorems. On the other hand, in a topology course, the concept of a path is fundamental (sic), because it allows to define a new way to understand objects.

Comment: @FormerMath So why $(t^2 - 1 , t^3 + 1)$ is a path ?

Comment: Because if you evaluate $t$ for all values $t\in [0,1]$ you can mark the resulting points in the XY plane, obtaining a line (not a straight one): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot

Comment: @FormerMath Why we restrict the domain to $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Just for simplicity.

Comment: You can think of it in terms of sequences instead of continuous paths. If there is are sequences $(x_n, y_n)$ and $(z_n, t_n)$ which converges to $(a, b)$, but $(f(x_n, y_n))$ don't converge to the same value as $(f(z_n, t_n))$, then function is not continuous at $(a, b)$.

Comment: @enedil How we can prove that ?

Comment: What definition of continuity do you assume?

Comment: @enedil The definition with the epsilon and delta .

Comment: Look at this, but replace every absolute value with norm (ex. $||(x, y)|| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643588/heine-definition-of-limit-of-a-function-at-infinity-using-sequences